# ASP.NET Core jquery window.location parameters not getting through

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

In my cshtml I have a link button ( control) with the following jquery script triggered on click:

```js
$('.content').on('click', 'a.export', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var idSelect = '';
    $('#ddlSelect option:selected').each(function () {
        idSelect += $('#ddlSelect')[0].value;
    });

    var idSelect2 = '';
    $('#ddlSelect2 option:selected').each(function () {
        idSelect2 += $('#ddlSelect2')[0].value;
    });

    var url = 'Home/Exports/' + 'param1=' + idSelect + '&param2=' + idSelect2;

    window.location = url;
});
```

this works as expected and I get for example an **url='Home/Spremljanja/Exports/param1=2019&param2=743'**

Now in my Home controller there is an Action to return a file:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public virtual IActionResult Exports(int param1, int param2)
{
    var path = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    var list = List(param1, param2);

    var file = new Document
    {
        Title = string.Format("Export bla bla - {0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")),
        Extension = ".xlsx",
        ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    };

    file.Contents = Backend.Helpers.Reports.Reports.Report1(path, list).ToArray();

    return File(file.Contents, file.ContentType, file.Title);
}
```

Now, no matter what parameter values in the URL passed via **window.location** are, I always get both param1 and param2 = 0 in the ActionResult. Why?

Comment: It's because you've missed the `?` in the URL to denote the querystring: `Home/Spremljanja/Exports/?param1=2019&param2=743`

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid right now. I lost 1h on this. Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action's parameters are set from proper query string parameters.
Try using '?' instead of '/' in your url initialization like this:
var url = 'Home/Exports?' + 'param1=' + idSelect + '&param2=' + idSelect2;
so your url looks like this:
url='Home/Spremljanja/Exports?param1=2019&param2=743'